# If loop is not working in AngularJS function

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins

I am new to ionic therefore to cordova so in my controllers .js i am having a function defined as :

```
$scope.deleteFingerPrint = function() {
  $scope.disableFingerPrint = true;
  ss.remove(
    function(key) {
      console.log('Removed ' + key);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('Error, ' + error);
    },
    'token');
  localStorage.removeItem('isFingerPrintRequired');
  localStorage.removeItem('hasEnrolledFingerprints');
  isFromIosUserValidation = false;
  $scope.deletePopup.close();
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
}
```

The code works fine but if i try to modify it like this:

```
$scope.deleteFingerPrint = function() {
  $scope.disableFingerPrint = true;
  ss.remove(
    function(key) {
      console.log('Removed ' + key);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('Error, ' + error);
    },
    'token');
  localStorage.removeItem('isFingerPrintRequired');
  localStorage.removeItem('hasEnrolledFingerprints');
  if (isIOS == true) {
    isFromIosUserValidation = false;
  }
  $scope.deletePopup.close();
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
}
```

The popup comes but $scope.deletePopup.close(); doesnot works and the popup remains as it is.
What is the issue and why it is not getting closed. I have mentioned isIOS and isFromIosUserValidation globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you define your isIOS variable, maybe the condition is not working so it give error. Please write code properly to understand the problem.

Comment: it is not defined globally :) finally i found it. Happy